# why does "Could not locate ordinal parameter [0], expecting one of []" happen?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using Hibernate as ORM. When I searched about this error, it was said that my problem is due to mapping but I checked it and didn't find any problem in it

My query is :

```
select result from com.a.b.c.loan.ArchiveHistory result where result.id =?
```

The mapping is :

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.a.b.c.loan.ArchiveHistory" mutable="false" table="ARCT_HISTORY_VIEW">

        <id name="id" column="BIBLIOGRAPHICID" type="long" unsaved-value="0">
        </id>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As it's stated in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#jpql-api):

> JPQL-style positional parameters are declared using a question mark followed by an ordinal - `?1`, `?2`. *The ordinals start with 1*. Just like with named parameters, positional parameters can also appear multiple times in a query.

So, try to rewrite your query in this way:

```java
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(
   "select result from com.a.b.c.loan.ArchiveHistory result where result.id =?1"
).setParameter( 1, 23L );
```

Or, as more readable alternative, I would suggest to use parameter binding by names:

```java
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(
   "select result from com.a.b.c.loan.ArchiveHistory result where result.id = :id"
).setParameter("id", 23L );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , However the error occurs before this statement .I mean It doesn't even meet this line .

Comment: OK, please provide related code snippet and full stack trace of your exception.

Comment: For me this happened since I forgot to add the DeltaSpike `@FirstResult` annotation to the `int offset` parameter and the `@MaxResults` to the `int limit`

Comment: I do not really understand that when one is using JPQL, marking question marks with ordinal is mandatory. Why not use a default order of 1...2...3... if one is not defining ordinals? Is there any specific reasoning behind this? I could only assume syntax is expected to be this way to raise awareness of a developer.

Answer (score 1):

Hope the following code snippet would answer your problem.

```
Query query = session.createQuery("FROM UserEntity where email=?1 and status=?2");
    query.setParameter(1,"abc@email.com");
    query.setParameter(2,"in");
    query.executeUpdate();
```

when we want to use positional parameters within a HQL query, we have to declare these as ordinal parameters that start with 1 and following '?'.